# Accessing DOM object after AJAX call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom

I have a typical AJAX call that appends some HTML to the current page. I want to be able to access the newly inserted HTML with typical jQuery selectors.

Here's what I'd *like* to be able to do...

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   success: function(data) {
      $('body').append(data);
   }
});

$('#new_div').show();
```

`#new_div` would be some HTML element from the data I retrieved. I don't necessarily want to attach events to the new elements (like `click`), so using something like `.load()` or `.on()` doesn't work here (as far as I know).

I tried setting the `$.ajax()` call to a variable: `var new_div = $.ajax(...)` but that didn't get me anywhere.

Comment: a) Did you verify your ajax request actually works (with developer console, alerts or firebug) and b) what is its output?

Comment: Yep, request works fine. Output when trying to access the new DOM element outside of the success call is just undefined.

Comment: AJAX is asynchronous so the `new_div` hasnt been appended yet

Answer (score 14):

If you would like to manipulate the new content immediately after (or even before) inserting it to the DOM, you can put that in the AJAX success callback too:

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   success: function(data) {
      $('body').append(data);
      $('#new_div').show();
   }
});
```

On the other hand, if you want to bind handlers to content that will be added to the page via ajax, jQuery does that like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '#new_div', function(){
  alert("This function is bound to all #new_div's click events, even if they are added to the DOM via ajax later!")
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to decouple your code from the callback:

```
functionWithALotOfStuffToDo = function(data){
  // do stuff here
}

$.ajax({
   url: url,
   success: functionWithALotOfStuffToDo
});
```

Answer (score 2):

how about:

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   success: function(data) {
      $('body').append(data).find('#new_div').show();
   }
});
```

Comment: There's a lot of additional stuff I need to do. Not *just* `show()`. I need to access it outside of the success call.

Comment: What do you actually want to do?

Comment: What do I actually want to do with the DOM element? All sorts of things. There's a slew of other functions I have that need to access the newly-inserted DOM elements.

Comment: Why can't you call these functions from the success callback?

Comment: I guess I could...was just trying to not stuff a ton of stuff in to that success callback. Felt messy to do it that way.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data being returned is something like `<div id='new_div' />` then try something such as

```
var newDiv = null;

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
        newDiv = $(data).appendTo($('body'));
    }
});
```

This will add the `<div />` to the body of your page, and assign the jQuery element to the variable `newDiv` which can then be accessed again at a later stage.

However, if you access `newDiv` before `success` has been returned, it will be `null` or the previous value, if it was assigned previously.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this sort of things can be solved by following way:
(I know it is similar to others, but a little bit more clear)

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   success: function(data) {
      $('body').append(data);
      afterHtmlAppendCallback();
   }
});
function afterHtmlAppendCallback()
{
    $('#new_div').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's ajax async cause the problem you mention.

In jQuery ajax funciton API says:
Perform an asynchronous HTTP (Ajax) request.

If you want to access the data from ajax right after request

you should put you code in the ajax.success function like:

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   success: function(data) {
      $('body').append(data);
      $('#new_div').show();
   }
});
```

Or turn the async setting into false

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   async:false,
   success: function(data) {
      $('body').append(data);
   }
});
$('#new_div').show();
```

that will make sure the $('#new_div') selector gets the object

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue and find a method that was great.

If you have the jQuery functions in a file for example `library_jquery.js`, just load that file again in the success.

```
$.ajax({
   url: url,
   success: function(data) {
      $('body').append(data);
      //LOAD THE SCRIPT FILE AGAIN
      var path_script_file="libray_jquery.js";
      $.getScript(path_script_file);
   }
});
```