# notify.js does not work for ajax response elements

Tags: jquery-plugins, notifyjs

I have an easy form like this:

```
<form>
    <fieldset>
        <label class="col-md-4">quantity</label>
        <input id="qta" type="text" data-validate="required,number">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class='form-group col-md-6'>
        <label class='col-md-4'>price</label>
        <input id='price' type='text' data-validate='required'>
    </fieldset>
    <input type='submit' value='insert'>
</form>
```

if this form is load in the page as an ajax response, notify does not work, why?
Typing all content between form tags in a simple `.php` page (without ajax call) notify works well.
Should I change ajax call settings? Is it a ajax call problem?

Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

Usually you shoud trigger notify when your ajax response returns

```
$.post(
    urlPath,
    function(response) {
        if (// check response validity) {
            noty({
                // your notify configuration
            });
        }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

So..is the question: accessing dom element after ajax call?

I refer to:
[Accessing DOM object after AJAX call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614548/accessing-dom-object-after-ajax-call)

In my case, ajax call appends `<form>...</form>` content into form tags includes, as I posted yesterday, an input submit. Onclick a notify.js data validation should start (data-validate=required for ex.) but nothing.

According to you, I may directly trigger notify into ajax $.post{...}, but validations/notifications are not customised by me in this case (for ex. required, number, string...) and they should start without no more code typing..

How should I do?

Thks