# How to reload page after inserting data in database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have created a form which insert the location of some users in database and these data should appear in the page. The problem is that the page doesn't reload by itself after I fill the form but I have to make a page reload.Or if the page is opened in another browser it doesn't reload. Is there a way that this page reloads by itself without making any action after I insert some data in database from this form?

Comment: You don't need to reload the page, that's what [`ajax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) is for. But if you insist on reloading the page, then yeah, sure it can be done. you can use [`location.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

Comment: @Andrew what ajax function should I use to not make the reload?

Comment: The whole idea is to not reload. Page reloads are not visually appealing and depending on the net connection can be quite slow. Don't reload, update on the go. Make an ajax call, return whatever info you need and update the DOM without reloading the page.

Comment: @Andrew any answer with the corresponding code to do that? I ll vote it up if functions.

Comment: Take some time to read on how to do an ajax and how it works. It's much more important to understand than to copy+paste blindly. [See here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614548/accessing-dom-object-after-ajax-call), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1510011/how-does-ajax-work).

Comment: Use `location.reload()` in success block.

Answer (score 2):

Use the assign() method. The assign() method is supported in all major browsers.

```
window.location.assign(data); "data being the URL"
```

or

```
window.location.href
```

```js
function myFunction() {
    location.assign("http://www.example.com");
}
```

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">Load new document</button>
```

> Ok thanks! Functions onClick eventhough I have an ng-click in side this button?

Yes it will still function properly. See JSFiddle [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/norcaljohnny/nnyyf44p/)

Edit: I saw you had this in your code?

```
window.history.back(); or location.reload();
```

consider replacing with with:

```
window.location.replace("pagehere.html");
```

Comment: And the data what should be?

Comment: the url you went them to go to.

Comment: Ok thanks! Functions onClick eventhough I have an ng-click in side this button?

Answer (score 1):

You can refresh the page after your completing your operation using jquery as

Javascript 1.0

```
window.location.href = window.location.pathname + window.location.search +window.location.hash;
// creates a history entry
```

Javascript 1.1

```
window.location.replace(window.location.pathname + window.location.search + window.location.hash);
// does not create a history entry
```

Javascript 1.2

```
window.location.reload(false);
```

Comment: #something can be the id of a button?

Comment: Yes you can use id of button or write it document.ready function

Comment: I tried. If I have the same page in another browser this remains still with the same data, and not updated until you make a reload. But I want to reload by itself

Comment: What if I want to reload another page ? So I have thgis item #something which reloads another page. How to reload another page?

Comment: use window.location.href="your_another_page_url"

Comment: No this takes me to another page. But If I have this page operned in another pc or browser this page doesnt reload if the data are submited bu another pc.Right?